# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable: for dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I am trying to make a matrix with my data:

```py
matrix_model1   matrix_model2

7.0             2.0   
4.0             4.0
30.0            20.0
4.0             8.0
```

I am trying to calculate the value of intersection:

```
m = []
for i in range(0, len(df2)):
    m.append(len(set(df2['matrix_model1'].iloc[i]).intersection(df2['matrix_model2'].iloc[i])))
df2['Model1_Intersection'] = m
df2
```

But I am getting an error:
**TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable**
I tried to change it to `int` by `.astype('Int64')` but it does not work, can anyone tell where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a single value into `set()` which causes this error

```
>>> set(5.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Your loop currently tries to create a `set` for each value in `matrix_model1` and `matrix_model2` (which fails)

If you're trying to find the intersection between `matrix_model1` to `matrix_model2`, you may try

```
set(df2['matrix_model1']) & set(df2['matrix_model2'])
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to create a new column that denotes whether values in `matrix_model1` and `matrix_model2` match, then you may try

```
df2['intersection'] = [row['matrix_model2'] == row['matrix_model1'] for index, row in df2.iterrows()]
```

Comment: ok, now i got it, thank you for pointing out, i was wasting time unnecessarily :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Sanidhya Singh, you cannot get the intersection of two arrays like that. Either convert both array values to sets or use `np.intersect1d` if you want to work with arrays and do not want to convert them to sets:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"matrix_model1" : [7.0, 4.0, 30.0, 4.0], "matrix_model2": [2.0, 4.0, 20.0, 8.0]})

m = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    m.append(len(set(np.intersect1d(df['matrix_model1'].iloc[i], df['matrix_model2'].iloc[i]))))
    
df['Model1_Intersection'] = m
df
```

Since you are only comparing `floats`, I highly recommend using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of looping through your data. It is much faster.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"matrix_model1" : [7.0, 4.0, 30.0, 4.0], "matrix_model2": [2.0, 4.0, 20.0, 8.0]})
df['Model1_Intersection'] = np.where(df['matrix_model1'].eq(df['matrix_model2']), 1, 0)
df

--------------------------------------------------------
    matrix_model1   matrix_model2   Model1_Intersection
0   7.0             2.0             0
1   4.0             4.0             1
2   30.0            20.0            0
3   4.0             8.0             0
--------------------------------------------------------
```